# tuleap installation on docker instance centos 7 gives error

Tags: tuleap

Should this OS version *centos 7 give a problem on docker instance ?

It is giving me following errors.

Error: Package: 3:mailman-tuleap-2.1.12-18.2.el6.x86_64 (Tuleap)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.80-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: perl-suidperl
Error: Package: gitolite-2.3.1-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.80-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: vixie-cron >= 4.1-9
Error: Package: 3:mailman-tuleap-2.1.12-18.2.el6.x86_64 (Tuleap)
           Requires: vixie-cron >= 4.1-9
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.80-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: mod_auth_mysql
Error: Package: tuleap-all-8.0.99.80-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation, Tuleap only works on Centos 6.X as of today.

There is a [ticket](https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=8036) tracking Centos 7 effort.